# R Studio - grepl compare a column in a dataframe to a list of pattern

Tags: r, regex

I have a column named "MATCH" in a dataframe and a list of patterns named "PATTERN".

```
df1.MATCH <- c("ABC", "abc" ,"BCD")
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1.MATCH)
df2.PATTERN <- c("ABC", "abc", "ABC abc")
```

I want to use grepl to compare MATCH column with PATTERN, if true, I will apply my functions. The desired result would be "ABC" matches "ABC" and "ABC abc". This is the code I used:

```
df1 %>% filter(grepl(df1.MATCH,df2.PATTERN ))%>% ...
```

I get error:

```
"Warning message: In grepl(TXN_GROUP, parm[3]) :argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"
```

I understand I can't use grepl to a list of vectors. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I can use filter(grepl(paste(df1.MATCH, collapse = "|"),df2.PATTERN )) and that works for this example. However, my real dataframe has ~1M rows and I got error when using this code.

Comment: On the first row of your code example, should it say `df1.MATCH <- c("ABC", "abc" ,"ABC")` rather than the last string being `"BCD"`?

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR: `grepl` expects its first argument to be a string (length 1), not a vector. You can solve this with combinations of `sapply` and `lapply` (see below), but you are better served using a single regular expression that captures what you want to match in `df1.MATCH` and not use `df2.PATTERN` at all. This second option is much faster (if less intelligle) for a large data set. For this type of work, it is worth learning how to use regular expressions to their full potential.

```
df1 %>% filter(grepl(pattern = "^((ABC)( )*)+$", x = df1.MATCH, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

**Explanation**

The documentation for `grepl` shows the following usage:

```
grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
  fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

The `pattern` argument is first, and this argument should be a string (one element). You are providing `df1.MATCH` to this argument, which is a vector.

We could use `sapply` to apply `grepl` to each element of `df1.MATCH`.

```
sapply(df1.MATCH, grepl, x = df2.PATTERN)
       ABC   abc   BCD
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

However, look at the output! You probably did not want a matrix. What happens when we run your `grepl` one just the first element of `df1.MATCH`?

```
grepl("ABC",df2.PATTERN)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

We get a vector because `grepl` is checking `ABC` against each element of `df2.PATTERN`. To get a useful logical vector for filtering, you need to return a logical vector of the same length as `df1.MATCH`. I see two ways to do it.

> Method 1: Use `any`

Since you want to know which elements in `df1.MATCH` match any elements in `df2.PATTERN`, you can use `any`, which returns `TRUE` if any element in its arguments is `TRUE`. We need a little bit different syntax to make this work. We need to wrap `grepl` in `lapply` to make a list of three vectors (one for each element in `df1.MATCH1`) that feeds into `sapply` wrapped `any`. If we just use `sapply`, `any` will only return one value since we have a matrix input.

```
any(grepl("ABC", df2.PATTERN))
[1]  TRUE

sapply(
  lapply(df1.MATCH, grepl, x = df2.MATCH),
  any)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

> Method 2: Write a better regular expression.

You want to match the contents of `df1.MATCH` against possible values that look like `abc`, `ABC`, `ABC ABC`, or `ABC abc`, etc. You can encompass all of this in a single regex string. The string you want is

```
"^((ABC)( )*)+$"
^                   # Nothing else before this
(ABC)               # Must contain ABC together as a group
( )*                # followed by any number of spaces (including 0)
((ABC)( )*)+        # Look for the ABC (space) pattern repeated one or more times
$                   # And nothing else after it
```

Then use `grepl` with `ignore.case = TRUE`:

```
grepl("^((ABC)( )*)+$", df1.MATCH, ignore.case = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
```

> Benchmarking

In a large dataset, one of these will perform faster. Let's find out. Your benchmark results will vary by your machine's resources.

```
df1.MATCH <- sample(c("ABC", "abc" ,"BCD"), size = 100000, replace = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(df1.MATCH) 
df2.PATTERN <- c("ABC", "abc", "ABC abc")

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark("any lapply" = {
              df1 %>% 
                filter(sapply(lapply(df1.MATCH, grepl, x=df2.PATTERN), any) )
          }, 
         "better regex" = {
              df1 %>%
                filter(grepl("^((ABC)( )*)+$", df1.MATCH, ignore.case = TRUE))
          }
          )

          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1   any lapply          100  149.13   70.678    147.67     0.39         NA        NA   
2 better regex          100    2.11    1.000      2.10     0.02         NA        NA
```

It looks like the improved regex method is significantly faster. That's because it is performing only one operation per row (`grepl`) before filtering. The other method is performing four operations per row: `lapply` is performing `grepl` three times (one for each element of `df2.PATTERN`, and `sapply` then performs `any` for each list element (each row).

Comment: Using `str_detect` from `package::stringr` performs similarly to the `grepl` approach: 
`str_detect(df1.MATCH, regex("^((ABC)( )*)+$", ignore_case = TRUE))`